# How to calculate the sum of every n number in a Vector in R?

Tags: r

I try to calculate the sum of every n number in a vector. I built a function to calculate it, but I am sure there should be some more convenient way to do that.

Assume it is my vector:

```
vector = c(1,5,6,8,10,23,1,10,123,1)
```

My function is to calculate the sum of every n number:

```
Sum_N <- function(vector, n ){

  result <- c()

  for(i in seq(1:(length(vector)-n+1))){

    result[i] <- sum(vector[i:(i+n-1)])

   }

 return(result)
}
```

The result is a vector:

```
### Sum_N(vector,3)
### 12  19  24  41  34  34 134
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the TTR package

```html
 TTR::runSum(vector, 3)
[1]  NA  NA  12  19  24  41  34  34 134 134
```

it will give you a vector of same size....you have the option of removing NAs

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `roll_sum` from `RcppRoll`

```
RcppRoll::roll_sum(vector, 3, fill= NA, align = "right")
#[1]  NA  NA  12  19  24  41  34  34 134 134
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for the `filter` function (that's `stats::filter` to be specific):

```
filter(vector, rep(1,3), sides=1)
#Time Series:
#Start = 1 
#End = 10 
#Frequency = 1 
# [1]  NA  NA  12  19  24  41  34  34 134 13
```

If the time series output causes problems, just flatten back to a vector:

```
c(filter(vector, rep(1,3), sides=1))
# [1]  NA  NA  12  19  24  41  34  34 134 134
```